# Is joining 1-to-1 tables always necessary?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four MySQL tables where the first three share the first tables PK, and the forth has a FK to the third table (see below for schema).

Given the PK of the forth table, I need data from the first and forth table only.

Is there any need to join the second and third table?

For instance, is:

```
SELECT t1.*,t4.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_idt1=t1.idt1
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.t2_idt2=t2.idt2
INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.t3_idt3=t3.idt3
WHERE t4.idt4=123;
```

better or worse than:

```
SELECT t1.*,t4.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.t3_idt3=t1.idt1
WHERE t4.idt4=123;
```

Please explain why one is better than the other.

SCHEMA

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 08/29/14 12:34:46
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t1` (
  `idt1` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idt1`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t2` (
  `t1_idt1` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t1_idt1`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t2_t1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t1_idt1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t1` (`idt1`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t3`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t3` (
  `t2_t1_idt1` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t2_t1_idt1`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t3_t21`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t2_t1_idt1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t2` (`t1_idt1`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t4`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t4` (
  `t3_t2_t1_idt1` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  INDEX `fk_t4_t31_idx` (`t3_t2_t1_idt1` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t4_t31`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t3_t2_t1_idt1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t3` (`t2_t1_idt1`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: There's no need to join a table if you don't use anything from it.

Comment: @Barmar  The reason I asked is I wasn't sure if performance would be impacted due to the indexes.

Comment: @Barmer.  Please answer the question stating so, then if you get voted down, I know you might not be right :)

Comment: Joining extra tables will definitely impact performance. The query planner doesn't know that there's a 1-to-1 relationship, so it doesn't know that the extra joins are redundant.

Comment: @The Down Voter.  Please explain why.  I searched for an answer before asking this question, and I felt it was an important question.  Thanks

Comment: It is extremely rare to want to have 3 or more tables with identical PKs.  What is the logic behind this schema design?  Couldn't all the columns be in a single table?

Comment: @RickJames  Funny that I haven't in 8 years really came to consensus on this one, and have just two weeks ago toyed with the idea of asking "why ever use 1-to-1 associations".  My only reasons why they should be used (assuming I didn't forget about something I was thinking about 2 weeks when I was thinking about this) are to enforce inheritance with SQL and value objects.

Comment: @user1032531 - Example: A social media app with a Like and/or View counter -- separate those column(s) into a separate table to decrease interference between the Updates and other traffic.  As for inheritance, ... I try to steer users away from that.

Comment: @Ric"As for inheritance, ... I try to steer users away from that"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to join any tables if they're not relevant to the query. A table is relevant if you need to refer to it columns, or you want the result set limited to rows that have matches in that table. Joining with extra tables will slow down the query, because the query planner cannot determine that these joins are redundant; there's no way to tell the DBMS that there's a 1-to-1 relationship between two tables. The best you can do is declare foreign key relationships -- the foreign key is required to be a subset of the values in the other table; but there's no way to declare exact equivalence. In fact, even if you intend to have 1-to-1 equivalence, you don't actually have it -- when you insert into the three tables, you have to do them sequentially, so for a brief period there's an extra row in one or two of the tables.

You can see that the query planner makes use of the extra tables if you compare the result of `EXPLAIN` between the two queries.

Comment: @user2864740 The query planner cannot automatically exclude the joins, because of the possibility that rows may be missing, and would thus be removed from the inner join.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge Ah, thanks - I see this case now. That information should be up in the answer.

Comment: I've added some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  Don't know if it is relevant, but my PK is not auto-incrementing, but is a random INT value.  They are done so so the site will not "appear" brand new and to make predicting the next inserted record PK more difficult.  Will this cause significant performance issues?

Comment: @Barmar - MariaDB seems to be smarter -- it removes Joins that aren't needed.  (But, as you say, there may be cases where it can't figure it out.)

Comment: @user1032531 - If the table is much bigger than RAM, "random" PKs tend to be slow because of cache issues.

Answer (score 1):

If all IDs are the same in all four tables, and if you don't want to exclude records that don't appear in tables 2 and 3, then there is no reason to include them in the join. It will still use the index on table 1, even without the foreign key relationship.

I would consider renaming all the ID columns to signify the fact that they are the same.

Comment: On your later point, if my tables are "entities", "people", "friends", and "cars_that_friends_drive", all should reference "entities"?  Instead of "people", I might have a table called "animals", and obviously animals don't drive.

Comment: @user1032531 - Fair enough. I'll remove that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is much better, the query only get the data from the two required tables instead of applying the jointure between two additional tables that you don't need.

I suggest you to change just the place of your condition:

```
SELECT t1.*,t4.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.t3_idt3=t1.idt1
                AND t4.idt4=123
```

By doing so, only the required data are loaded from t4 instead of loading every data and then applying the `WHERE` condition on the result.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  Others, please comment if you agree or disagree.  Thanks

Comment: If you have the possibility to compare the performance between the query with the `WHERE`clause and the one i provided, please share your feedback.

Comment: Will do, however, I need to learn how to do so, so it might be a few days. Thanks